# How to view the SQL Server CE 3.5 database table values?

Tags: windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I am using VS 2012 for Windows Phone Development. For my app I am using to create database and `Context` class (.cs file) from SQL Server CE 3.5 Toolbox. I add this `.sdf` file and context class in to my project.

I can store and retrieve data using these two files. But I unable to view what I store in the database. If I connect `.sdf` file using SQL Server Compact 3.5 tool for runtime. I could not get stored data, I am only able to view the tables.

Please anyone give me the solution to view the stored data when WP8 operation performed?

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows Phone Power Tools to copy the s.df file from the device to your desktop, and open it in the Toolbox